# Integrar adminlte por npm en laravel

Tags: laravel, adminlte, laravel-7

tengo un problema al integrar la plantilla adminlte a un proyecto nuevo de laravel 7.

Ejecuté los siguientes comandos

```
php artisan ui bootstrap
npm install admin-lte --save
```

Integré en `resources` lo siguiente para las carpetas correspondientes

```
// resources/js/bootstrap.js
require('admin-lte');

// resources/sass/
@import '~admin-lte/dist/css/adminlte.css';
@import "../css/_all-skins.css"; // Archivo manual que no se encuentra en node_modules
```

Sin embargo, al compilar y ejecutar el sitio, se ve de la siguiente forma.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Nunca usé el paquete, pero le dí una mirada a la documentación y tiene varias dependencias, como jquery y bootstrap3. Puede ser?

Comment: Ya las incluí previamente.